# Reproducing code from Calendar API Explorer in Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm playing with the API explorer: http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.calendarList.list

I can get that work, (after authenticating with OAuth). The request looks something like this:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?fields=items(description%2Ckind%2Csummary)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:`Bearer ya29.1.FGDtN_WzfD1qNt86qJJlIwR65hdr1sU6BYqndDRPgyMF5xVK2olOacitZH41hQ`
X-JavaScript-User-Agent: `Google APIs Explorer`

I'm trying to reproduce that using Jersey (keys and stuff have been changed):

```
String apikey = "blah-blah-e2GB-yZp7CasdfoC8Bm10ZDhCpk";
String getCals = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList";

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(getCals);
target = target.queryParam("fields", "items(description%2Cid%2Ckind%2Csummary)");
target = target.queryParam("key", apikey);


Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
builder.header("Authorization:", "Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_WzfDabsdwerwer0d0f0ndDRPgyMF5xVK2olOacitZH41hQ");
Response response = builder.get();
int status = response.getStatus();
String ret = response.readEntity(String.class);
log.debug("status: " + status + " response:\n" + ret);
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work - I get this back:

```
jerseyTest App - status: 401 response:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Can anyone see why?

Comment: Where did you get the access token ya29.1.FGDtN_WzfD1qNt86qJJlIwR65hdr1sU6BYqndDRPgyMF5xVK2olOacitZH41hQ from? and how long before your test did you get it (given the token expires after 1 hour)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify user, for which you want to list calendars. In 2-legged OAuth you can specify user using `xoauth_requestor_id` parameter. Please, see this link [Calendar API v3, 2-legged OAuth & Java](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/calendar-api-v3-2-legged-oauth-java.html) for more information. But, I think this is not the main problem. The main problem is the fact that you can not use `Authorization` header from API Explorer. You have to generate new one for your `API-key` and `secret`. See this page [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) for more information. In Java you can use very good library which Google developed for Calendar API: [google-api-services-calendar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-calendar). I suggest to use this library instead of generating native query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will follow your suggestions.